# Как удаленно установить мое тестовое приложение человеку на iphone?

Tags: ios, установка

Есть ли способ удаленно установить мое приложение человеку на iphone не подключая его к своему маку?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно. Есть такая штука как [diawi](http://www.diawi.com). UDID девайса должен быть включен в провижн профайл, под которым ты собираешь билд. После этого ты перетягиваешь собранный ипа файл и провижн профайл в окошко diawi, туда где написано drag files here. Затем жмешь кнопку send. Будет сгенерена ссылка, которую ты отправляешь заказчику. Все что ему нужно - открыть эту ссылку у себя на девайсе и приложение будет установлено.

Этот вариант подразумевает что заказчику вообще ни к какому маку можно не подключаться. Из твоего текста нельзя однозначно сделать вывод о чьем маке идет речь. Если ты имеешь в виду свой собственный мак (в то время как заказчик может юзать его (заказчика) мак), то можно просто отправить ему билд и он сможет поставить его себе на девайс через iTunes (разумеется, при условии, что UDID девайса включен в провижн). Но diawi, на мой взгляд, самая удобная и быстрая опция.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно устанавливать приложение на любой девайс даже не зная его UDID. Достаточно e-mail владельца девайса. Больше того, о последующих версиях приложения владелец девайса будет своевременно уведомлен и при желании может ее установить. Это [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). Как видите, это официальная технология, и принадлежит Apple. Очень полезная вещь для тестирования. [Инструкции по настройке.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)